# Optimal lag selection in Granger Causality tests

Tags: stata, causality

I use `[TS] varsoc` to obtain the optimum lag length for the Granger causality test in Stata. This command reports the optimal number of lags based on different criteria such as Akaike's information criterion (AIC).
Is there any way to store the optimal lag number (obtained based on AIC) in a variable and use it in the next command to estimate causality? Something like this:

```
Lag= varsoc X Y
tvgc X Y, p(Lag) d(Lag) trend window(30) prefix(_) graph
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I adapt the first example in the help for `varsoc`. You can sort the matrix of statistics so that minimum AIC is in the first row, and read off the lag concerned.

```
. webuse lutkepohl2, clear 
(Quarterly SA West German macro data, Bil DM, from Lutkepohl 1993 Table E.1)

. varsoc dln_inv dln_inc dln_consump

Lag-order selection criteria

   Sample: 1961q2 thru 1982q4                               Number of obs = 87
  +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | Lag |    LL      LR      df    p     FPE       AIC      HQIC      SBIC    |
  |-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |   0 |  696.398                     2.4e-11  -15.9402  -15.9059  -15.8552* |
  |   1 |  711.682  30.568    9  0.000 2.1e-11  -16.0846  -15.9477* -15.7445  |
  |   2 |  724.696  26.028    9  0.002 1.9e-11* -16.1769* -15.9372  -15.5817  |
  |   3 |  729.124  8.8557    9  0.451 2.1e-11  -16.0718  -15.7294  -15.2215  |
  |   4 |  738.353  18.458*   9  0.030 2.1e-11  -16.0771   -15.632  -14.9717  |
  +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   * optimal lag
   Endogenous: dln_inv dln_inc dln_consump
    Exogenous: _cons

. 
. mata 
------------------------------------------------- mata (type end to exit) ---------------
: stats = st_matrix("r(stats)")

: _sort(stats, 7)

: st_numscalar("opt_lag_AIC", stats[1,1])

: end 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. di opt_lag_AIC 
2
```

To plug into a later command automatically, use expressions like

```
`=opt_lag_AIC'
```

as arguments to options.

Comment: Thank you. It's really helpful.
If optimal lag=0, I want to replace it with 1 and plug it into a later command automatically. How can I do that?

Comment: `scalar opt_lag_AIC = max(1, opt_lag_AIC)`